# When do you encounter issues with encodings in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I have recently learned more in depth about ASCII, Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc. in Python3, but I am struggling to understand when would one run into issues while reading/writing to files.

So if I open a file:

```
with open(myfile, 'a') as f:
    f.write(stuff)
```

where stuff = 'Hello World!'
I have no issues writing to a file.
If I have something like:
non_latin = '娜', I can still write to the file with no problems.

So when does one run into issues regarding encodings? When does one use encode() and decode()?

Comment: You run into issues if you don't use the same encoding for encoding and decoding. You need to encode/decode if you want to handle strings vs byte arrays. If you just want read a text file, you have to add the encoding if it is not written in UTF-8. Basically all of this is covered [in this documentation](https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

You run into issues if the default encoding for your OS doesn't support the characters written.  In your case the default (obtained from `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`) is probably UTF-8.  On Windows, the default is an ANSI encoding like `cp1252` and wouldn't support Chinese.  Best to be explicit and use `open(myfile,'w',encoding='utf8')` for example.